# Efficient shingling algorithm

Tags: python, performance, parsing, text, n-gram

Im have implemented the following algorithm to extract groups of n words from a string.

```
def ngrams(text, size):
    tokens = text.split()
    ngrams = []
    for char in range(len(tokens)):
        if (len(tokens)-char) < size:
            break
        list_shingle = tokens[char:char+size]
        str_shingle = ' '.join(list_shingle)
        ngrams.append(str_shingle)
    return ngrams
```

The strings have such form:

```
['Hello my name is Inigo Montoya, you killed my father, prepare to die.']
```

The output should look like this, for a size of 3 words:

```
['Hello my name','my name is','name is Inigo',...,'prepare to die.']
```

I have to compare a large amount of documents, how can I make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a different algorithm, but it uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a loop:

```
def ngrams2(text, size):
    tokens = text.split()
    return [' '.join(tokens[i:i+size])
                     for i in range(len(tokens) - size + 1)]
```

At least on my machine, the change pays off:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from shingle import ngrams, ngrams2, text' 'ngrams(text, 3)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 501 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from shingle import ngrams, ngrams2, text' 'ngrams2(text, 3)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 usec per loop
```

(`text` is 10kb generated by https://www.lipsum.com/. It contains 1347 "words" in a single line.)